# How to redirect to another folder but so that it stays within same base url?

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect "product_brand" folder to "brands" but so that it follows the same url structure before it?

```
 RewriteRule ^/?product_brand/(.*)$ /brands/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If product is:

```
www.website.com/product_brand/nike
```

it should be:

```
www.website.com/brands/nike
```

but also if url is:

```
 www.website.com/another_folder/product_brand/nike
```

it should also work within that url:

```
www.website.com/another_folder/brands/nike
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match, capture and reuse part before `product_brand` in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?product_brand(/.*)?$ /$1brands$2 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Use a new browser to test the changes.

Comment: Hm it still redirects me to https://www.website.com/brands/abc with missing subfolder before (I am testing in different browser and also as a guest in Chrome) if url is https://www.website.com/something/product_brand/nike/

Comment: Make sure this is first rule in your site root (not in a subdir) .htaccess and there is no other .htaccess anywhere else.